# Подставить значение в input value

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как c помощью jquery или просто нативного js сделать, чтоб при загрузке страницы, если разметка содержит

```
<input type="hidden" name="h1" id="h1_form" value=""/>
```

в поле value подставлялся текст, содержащийся в h1

```
$(function () {
  var toInput = $('#h1_form').val = $('h1').text();
  console.log(toInput);
});
```

и после сабмита формы значение, содержащееся внутри value этого инпута будет отправляться вместе с остальными данными формы

Должно ли в DOM отображаться подставленное значение?
Если да - то что я делаю не правильно, если нет - то как это сделать?

Comment: [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) - Это функция, и чтобы установить значение ей надо передать параметр `$('#h1_form').val($('h1').text())`

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо! Вопрос решён)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 if($("h1").text()!=""){ // если h1 не пустое
      $("#h1_form").attr("value", $("h1").text()); //записываем значение в value
      }  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="h1" id="h1_form" value=""/>
<h1>Некий заголовок</h1>
```

Comment: Спасибо, с решением уже помогли в комментариях, но Ваш тоже подходит

Comment: а проверять на пустоту зачем?